# Is it possible to change default EventKitUI style?

Tags: iphone, ios, styling, eventkit

Is it possible to change default EventKitUI style? I'd like to have different background (transparent), also black translucent navigation bar and buttons.

Maybe there is a way to override default style for the whole app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  That is all controlled by apple.  You can change a few colors here and there.  Look at the documentation for UINavigationBar or whichever component you want to work with.  Some things have a color or style setting others like UIAlertView's do not.